# Create multi user selection field

Tags: list, column, spfield

how could i create a multi user field?

```
<Field
   ID="{6ec181bb-e64c-40cf-9a77-48c98108e981}"
   Name="Field"
   DisplayName="MyUserField"
   Type="UserMulti"
   Required="FALSE"
   Group="myGroup">
  </Field>

<Field
   ID="{6ec181bb-e64c-40cf-9a77-48c98108e981}"
   Name="Field"
   DisplayName="MyUserField"
   Type="UserMulti"
   Mult="True"
   Required="FALSE"
   Group="myGroup">
  </Field>
```

The first one wont work and the second one wont work, i can only select one user in the list that contains my field

Answer (score 1):

```
<Field Type="UserMulti" 
        DisplayName="MultiUser" 
        List="UserInfo" 
        ShowField="ImnName"             
        Mult="TRUE" 
        ID="{1f976bde-c0f1-48e6-acbd-dec4e9f08e4f}"
        Name="SomeName" />
```

This works for me